# DataProxy returned an error (Data transformation failed. TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string or Unicode, int found in CKAN

Tags: python, ckan

```
This resource view is not available at the moment.
Could not load view: DataProxy returned an error (Data transformation failed. TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string or Unicode, int found)
```

When i try to visualize excel file with datatype int this error is thrown by data explorer. I generated these files using numpy and pandas library. You can see the error for yourself [here](http://opendata.kp.gov.pk/dataset/performance-data-of-soil-conservation-2018/resource/a00ff0e8-4870-47db-b028-adb18a5527f9?view_id=2f76c23e-3ea4-4d1f-a008-7f374f7babbf#).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case the error was because the excel files had column headers with length greater than 63 characters. Reducing that, helped